# django - Is it possible to use a slug and primary in a url

Tags: django, django-urls

```
www.example.com/slug/PrimaryKey
www.example.com/foo/1
```

If so, how can I pass the variables in.

ex.

```
{% 'example:posts' slug='slug' pk=1 %} # would this work?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

urls.py:

```
# Django 2.0 
urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:slug>/<int:pk>', views.posts, name='posts'),
]

# Django 1.11 and bellow:
urlpatterns = [
    url('(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.posts, name='posts'),
]
```

template:

```
{% url 'posts' 'slug' 1 %}
```

If you pass a 'post' object to your template, which i think its your case, but i'm not sure:

```
{% url 'posts' post.slug post.pk %}
```